# Easy way to receive Gmail inbox activity summary at a different email address?

Tags: gmail

I'm currently switching email providers.

Is there an easy way to get a weekly summary at my new email of activity in my old Gmail inbox so I don't miss anything important during this transition period?

I don't want to forward my email, I just want a summary so I can go take care of it in Gmail, either by unsubscribing or changing where emails of that type are being sent.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to forward your the email to your new address.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the info. I'm assuming you're referring to within Gmail? Is it possible that a third-party service might make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) can monitor your Gmail inbox and create digests or forward select emails.

[Unroll.Me](https://unroll.me/) would help you summarize your inbox, but you'd have to combine it with IFTTT or forward the summaries to get them in your other inbox.

Comment: Thank you! +1, and will accept when I get my first successful digest. For those wondering, I set up an IFTTT recipe using the Gmail new email trigger and the Digest add to weekly digest action.